# Adjust implausible imputed values in an optimized way

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, missing-data, editing

I have a dataset with some imputed values. According to a predefined edit rule, some of these imputed values are implausible. For that reason, I want to adjust these implausible imputed values, but the adjustment should be as small as possible.

Here is a simplified example:

```
# Seed
set.seed(111)

# Example data
data <- data.frame(x1 = round(rnorm(200, 5, 5), 0),
                   x2 = factor(round(runif(200, 1, 3), 0)),
                   x3 = round(rnorm(200, 2, 10), 0),
                   x4 = factor(round(runif(200, 0, 5), 0)))
data[data$x1 > 5 & data$x2 == 1, ]$x3 <- 4
data[data$x1 > 5 & data$x2 == 1, ]$x4 <- 5

# Missings
data$x1[sample(1:nrow(data), 25)] <- NA
data$x2[sample(1:nrow(data), 50)] <- NA
data$x3[sample(1:nrow(data), 40)] <- NA
data$x4[sample(1:nrow(data), 35)] <- NA

# Imputation
library("mice")
imp <- mice(data, m = 1)

# Imputed data
data_imp <- complete(imp, "repeated")

# So far everything works well. 
# However, there is a predefined edit rule, which should not be violated.

# Edit Rule: 
# If x1 > 5 and x2 == 1 
# Then x3 > 3 and x4 > 4

# Because of the imputation, some of the observations have implausible values.
implausible <- data_imp[data_imp$x1 > 5 & data_imp$x2 == 1 & 
                          (data_imp$x3 <= 3 | (data_imp$x4 != 4 & data_imp$x4 != 5)), ]
implausible

# Example 1)
# In row 26 x1 has a value > 5 and x2 equals 1. 
# For that reason, x3 would have to be larger than 3 (here x3 is -17).
# Like you can see in the original data, x2 has been imputed in row 26.
data[rownames(implausible), ]
# Hence, x2 would have to be adjusted, so that it randomly gets a different category.

# Example 2)
# In row 182 are also implausible values. 
# Three of the variables have been imputed in this row. 
# Therefore, all/some of the imputed cells would have to be adjusted, 
# but the adjustment should be as small as possible.
```

I have already made some research and found some relevant papers/books, in which some optimization algorithms are described:

Pannekoek & Zhang (2011): https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269410841_Partial_donor_Imputation_with_Adjustments

de Waal, Pannekoek & Scholtus (2011): Handbook of Statistical Data Editing and Imputation

However, I am struggling with the implementation of these algorithms in R. Is there a Package available, which helps with these kind of calculations. I'd really appreciate some help with my code or some hints about the topic!

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78632/multiple-imputation-for-missing-values

Comment: Thanks for the link user20650, it helped to get some more insights about the topic. However, the question/answers in the linked thread are about constraints, which would be implemented before the imputation. In my case it is important, that the already imputed values are adjusted after the imputation.

Comment: ah ok. So you want to adjust the values of x3 and x4 if one or both of them are less than 3 or 4 , respectively, if x1 > 5 and x2 == 1 , and you want the adjustment to be as small as possible. Couldn't this be done by just setting x3 and/or x4 to 3 or 4 + epsilon when this condition is met.. ie this would be the minimum adjustment. Although I would think this would mess up the statistical properties of the imputation (standard errors etc). I actually, think this may be worth asking on http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions , although i'd rephrase it so that it is less R-centric.

Comment: x1 and x2 could also be adjusted, in case that they have been imputed before. The second example of my R-Code illustrates such a situation. Row 182 before imputation: x1 = NA; x2 = NA; x3 = -7; x4 = NA. After imputation: x1 = 6; x2 = 1; x3 = -7; x5 = 5. --> The edit rule is violated after the imputation. x1, x2, and x4 have been imputed and could therefore be adjusted. Which of these values should be adjusted, so that the change of the observation is as small as possible?

Comment: Thanks for your hint regarding stackexchange by the way. I will probably do that, in case I don't get an answer here.